# Android - Is it possible to use ui api in the other class and thread expect Activity?

Tags: android

I have some questions about android ui api.

Give a example, that I want to implement.

Main_UI_Thread.java :

```
public class Main_UI_Thread extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /*** do something about layout ***/
        ...

        DisplayClass dc = new DisplayClass();
        Thread th = new Thread(dc);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

DisplayClass.java :

```
public class DisplayClass extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if( something happen ) {
             to display Dialog or Toast show
             and handle the ui listener
        }
    }
}
```

I know the message passing can be do that;

But I want the ui program is be implemented in DisplayClass.java

Is it possible??

My English is  not well.^^"

Thanks everybody to give me some suggestions. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DisplayClass` would probably need a reference to your `Activity` instance, and modify the UI by calling the `Activity`'s methods (or UI modifying methods that accept the `Activity` instance as an argument).

Also, remember to always use the [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method to perform UI modifying actions from your "own" threads.

No need for DisplayClass to extend `Thread` if you are doing `new Thread(dc);`. Implementing Runnable is good enough.

```
public class DisplayClass extends Runnable {
    private Activity activity;
    public DisplayClass(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (something happen) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinks Lauri a lot.
 
I mistake the thread class.
 
I implemented this concept is work.
 
BTW, the Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
should add show function. 

So it can be Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Thanks a lot.